# How to use the Optional.ofNullable and Stream

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I am doing a test case to use Optional.ofNullable and Stream together, and I faced to ways to do the same, both have the same output.

```
List<String> list1 = List.of("abc","abc");
Optional.ofNullable(list1).stream().flatMap(List::stream).map(e -> e.concat("def")).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> list2 = List.of("abc","abc");
Stream<String> stream = Optional.ofNullable(list2).map(List::stream).orElseGet(Stream::empty);
stream.map(e-> e.concat("def")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My question is, why at the first example I use a **flatMap** and a **map** and at the second one I use two **map's** to do the same job. If I try to use two map's at the first example it doesn't work.

Comment: If you replace `flatMap` with `map`, then you end up with a `Stream<Stream<String>>`, not a `Stream<String>`.

Comment: I udnerstand the point, that if I replace the first one for map, it will return a Stream<Stream<String>> , but why in the second example, when I use the variable stream to receive it, it returns a Stream<String> ?

Comment: I read the documentation but it's continues not clear, why it's working this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand what's happening it can help to look at all the return types:

**First example:**

```java
List<String> list1 = List.of("abc","abc");

List<String> result = 
    Optional.ofNullable(list1)          // Optional<List<String>>
        .stream()                       // Stream<List<String>>
        .flatMap(List::stream)          // Stream<String>
        .map(e -> e.concat("def"))      // Stream<String>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());  // List<String>
```

In this example you go straight from an `Optional<List<String>>` to a `Stream<List<String>>` and then use the methods of the latter interface. The methods used here are (in order):

1. [`Optional#ofNullable(T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable(T))
2. [`Optional#stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#stream())
3. [`Stream#flatMap(Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function))
4. [`Stream#map(Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function))
5. [`Stream#collect(Collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector))

**Second example:**

```java
List<String> list2 = List.of("abc","abc");

List<String> result =
    Optional.ofNullable(list2)          // Optional<List<String>>
        .map(List::stream)              // Optional<Stream<String>>
        .orElseGet(Stream::empty);      // Stream<String>
        .map(e-> e.concat("def"))       // Stream<String>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());  // List<String>
```

In this example you go from an `Optional<List<String>>` to an `Optional<Stream<String>>` (another optional) and then extract the `Stream<String>` via `Optional#orElseGet(Supplier)`. Afterwards, you use the methods of the `Stream` interface. The methods used here are (in order):

1. [`Optional#ofNullable(T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable(T))
2. [`Optional#map(Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function))
3. [`Optional#orElseGet(Supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet(java.util.function.Supplier))
4. [`Stream#map(Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function))
5. [`Stream#collect(Collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector))

Comment: Though one should in practice really avoid `Optional.of**(Collection<>)`

Comment: First of all, Slaw, thanks for the really explained answer.

Comment: And Naman, why did you say that ? In this case, how would you do that without the Optional ? An if ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ArturReis An `Optional` is typically used only as a _return type_ to indicate the result may or may not be present. Creating an `Optional` locally just to use its methods and give your code a more functional style is frowned upon—at least by some of the community. I personally don't like it. Also, when a collection is used as the return type it's considered best practice to return an _empty_ collection to indicate no result, rather than `null`. So having an `Optional` containing a collection is suspect. I believe that's what Naman was referring to.

Comment: @ArturReis If this might be simple to understand, `Optional.empty` would represent the lack of data and `Collection.isEmpty` does the same. So, think of why would you require to wrap the `Collection` further inside an `Optional`. Besides assigning a null value to a Collection is an abuse of the API itself. Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej0sss6cq14&feature=youtu.be&t=27m51s) (from another comment) further.

Comment: `Optional.ofNullable(list1).stream()` is obsolete, you can directly use `Stream.ofNullable(list1)`

Comment: @Holger Agreed. Though my answer was focused on showing the OP what their current code was doing.

Comment: @ArturReis See Holger's comment.

Comment: **Slaw**, **Naman** and **Holger Agreed**

Thank you very much for the explanation, it was perfect to understand better the Optional and how to correctly use it.